# Bug: Cannot Use Chat When Over the Required Rep Amount

Tags: bug, support, chat

**Edit: This issue was fixed at 20:32, July 01. No one knows how or why.**

I have previously used chat (this morning in fact) and all the sudden, I log on and cant use it! I have over 110 reputation, and even more network-wide.

I have some pictures:

The GD.SE header:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/54PiG.png

The error message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDDSS.png

all of my accounts on SE

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM95j.png

My chat account (in @ToddersLegrande's answer) was at 0 rep, but now it is 178.... I have no idea why.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Edit: I just noticed that the 178 rep amount that i got is the combined amount of rep of all of my SE accounts, 111 from GD.SE, 52 from SO, 11 from The Workplace, 3 from Code Review, and 1 from Robotics. - 20:08 EST, July 01

Comment: Just for some basic troubleshooting (feel free to try again after each step): Restart browser; Clear cache/cookies on browser; Restart PC; - Just want to rule out the obvious here.

Comment: @ToddersLegrande hey man! i tried all of those :P none of them helped. Code and I were talking about this on the Google Hangouts

Comment: Try a different browser too maybe...

Comment: i shall, probably IE @ToddersLegrande

Comment: It's clear that the chat site is just defending itself from the overuse of stars.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136368/other-stack-exchange-accounts-are-not-shown-in-my-profile

Comment: Just did some spot checking and seems nobody has a profile right now. Still could be related at the root of things but I can't make a correlation as to why the chat issue only affects some users and how the chat issue can be fixed while this is still a problem... :|

Comment: @ToddersLegrande i have a new pic, its so wierd..... My chat account said my rep is 178 on GD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually had a similar problem now that I think of it.

[Chat.StackExchange Reputation Bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161257/chat-stackexchange-reputation-bug)

The mods were able to force refresh my account but I was able to get around it by switching my chat profile's parent account to a different StackExchange site and then back to GameDev.

Your chat account is here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/75273/theprogramm3r

There should be a [change] link right by the parent account field. See if that works for you.

[image: 0 rep chat profile]

** ***Assuming it was appropriate I would add the below details to the question if I could edit*** **

[JohnMcdonald disappeared around 9:18PM chat time](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10159033#10159033)

[JohnMcdonald reappared around 10:27PM chat time reporting similar problem as reported in the question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10160013#10160013)

John reported the following details regarding what he noticed around the incident:

Available: 
Rep on Gamedev; Check votes on Gamedev (needs some rep); Account on GD.SE, SO, and others; Chat on SO only

Not Available
Chat on anywhere except StackOverflow (sites affected included GD.SE and Arquade)

"Logging out and in didn't work, clearing cookies didn't work, using a different browser didn't work. I just had to wait 1 hour then everything was back to normal ... I was in chat at the time. I sent one message, and within 5 seconds, I tried to attach an image and it failed because I didn't have rep."

John reported that his network displayed exactly like the following image and was still displaying the symptom, though chat was now working. I have confirmed that TheProgramm3r's network profile is having the same issue as of right now.

[image: Empty Network Profile]

John was unable to confirm whether or not his chat profile showed zero reputation

Comment: thanks. ill try that!

Comment: i have to go to dinner now, so ill be back in >2 hours. tnx!

Comment: Yup. All true. Very strange. Usually clearing cookies works, but not this time.

Comment: @JohnMcDonald yeah. 

@ ToddersLeGrande still wont work :P Get on it SE employees!

Comment: Try again. Your chat rep came back. Log out and back in maybe?

Comment: its 178 tho... i only have 111 rep on GD.SE. I saw the test tho, but still cant post a message

Comment: Unfortunately I am out of ideas :(

Comment: Also, it's combined rep so the number there is correct.